# SQLiteDatabaseScope reference error

Tags: c#, sqlite

Inside one solution I have `SQLiteDatabaseScope` correctly referenced with no errors. On the other solution I'm getting frustrated cause I cannot referenced this dll either using nuget or explicitly referencing dll on the solution one hdd location.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
SQLiteDatabaseScope DbScope; // the type or namespace could not be found
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabaseScope` is *not* part of [the SQLite adapter](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), but is rather [from basicallyeverything](http://code.google.com/p/basiclyeverything/source/browse/trunk/NStackExample/Part10/CSharp/System.Data.SQLite.DatabaseScope/SQLiteDatabaseScope.cs?r=3) or another source.

Make sure the correct assembly (from "basicallyeverything") is referenced *or* the appropriate class source file is included in the project.

Remember that assembly names and namespaces *do not need to align* in .NET - it's just a nicety when they do.